# Subtracting percentage Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

```
 <cfset num = arguments.chosenNumber - (arguments.chosenNumber / 5)>
```

num needs to equal chosenNumber - 5%.

Comment: What is the question here? Can you add some information?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a coding question as much as it is a math question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if it needs to be - 5% it should be like this

```
 <cfset num = arguments.chosenNumber - (arguments.chosenNumber / 20)>
```

which comes from this

```
<cfset num = arguments.chosenNumber - (arguments.chosenNumber*5/100)>
```

or even easier

```
<cfset num = arguments.chosenNumber - (arguments.chosenNumber*0.05)>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is simple math. If you want to 'subtract' 5%, simply multiply by .95 to get the result.

```
<cfset num = arguments.chosenNumber * .95 />
```